# Custom C library: can functions in the same library refer to each other?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I've just started to create my own C libraries to keep my commonly used functions tidy. However, I've hit a new problem and I struggled to find information on the best route to take.

I generate my library of two functions using the following:

```
gcc -I. -c -fpic rand_site.c
gcc -I. -c -fpic rand_spin.c
gcc -shared -o libstatphys.so rand_site.o rand_spin.o
```

Each of these source files contained a single function. I was hoping to create a third function for my library that uses the two functions above but I'm not sure how to use functions from within the same library.

Am I going about this the right way? What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: Just use them like you normally would. There is nothing special about functions invoking other functions in the same library.

Comment: Within the same library, like @FilipeGonçalves says, there's no problem at all. If instead there were two libraries and each referred to the other, you would probably have to make special consideration on the linker command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Create a header file `rand_site.h` and put the declaration of the function defined in `rand_site.c` in it.

Create a header file `rand_spin.h` and put the declaration of the function defined in `rand_spin.c` in it.

Use `#include` to include the two `.h` files in the third file, say `foo.c`.

Then compile `foo.c` and add it to the library using:

```
gcc -I. -c -fpic foo.c
gcc -shared -o libstatphys.so rand_site.o rand_spin.o foo.o
```

If you would like to create a second shared library that has `foo.o`, you can use:

```
gcc -I. -c -fpic foo.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o -lstatphys
```

If you would like to create an executable using `foo.o`, you can use:

```
gcc -I. -c foo.c
gcc foo.o -lstatphys
```

Comment: So when the object files are linked, they are made aware of one another? I imagine that without being a part of the library, `foo.c` wouldn't be able to call those functions from separate source files.

Comment: Also, I'm using a single header file for the library `statphys.h` that all the source files include. So I can use that for my function declarations.

Comment: @oLas foo.c can call the functions in the library without being part of the library. That's how we are able to standard libraries and third party libraries.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if I compiled `foo.c` using the above line that doesn't use the library. This is where I was initially confused because `foo.c` is compiled without knowing where the other functions are (i.e. no -lstatphys flag), I know it will compile because it has declarations but if I was to try and use `foo.c` outside of the library it wouldn't find those source files? So the linking also shares the information between the object files?

Comment: @oLas If I understand you correctly, you don't want to include `foo.o` in the library. You just want to use the functions defined in the library in `foo.c`. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: No, your answer is perfect. I DO want to use `foo.c` in the library, the above answer is exactly what I wanted. I was just asking a follow up question about the nature of linking the files.

Comment: Looking at the last two lines of your answer. My follow up question is: IF I was to run `gcc -I. foo.c` (i.e. without `-c`), would the resulting executable `a.out` fail to run because it wouldn't be able to call the functions declared in the header file?

Comment: @oLas I expanded my answer that hopefully answers your questions.

Comment: @oLas, the answer to your last question: `gcc -I. foo.c` will fail to create `a.out`. You'll have to use `gcc -I. foo.c -lstatphys`.